# SQL group by in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query:

```
Select id, t1.column1 * t1.column2 as SUM from t1 Inner Join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

After execute get this result  https://postimg.org/image/r6yu7rp7n/

How add GROUP BY ID in query?

Comment: Please review [How to post a tsql question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) and [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you just need fields from t1 should do just

```
Select t1.id, 
       sum(t1.column1 * t1.column2) as SUM 
from t1 
Inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
group by t1.id
```

if need to apply some filters

```
Select t1.id, 
       sum(t1.column1 * t1.column2) as SUM 
from t1 
Inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
where t2.someField = someValue
group by t1.id
```

but, if you need to show the value of each line and the total for the group, you can use a windowed function like this

```
Select t1.*, 
       t2.*, 
       sum(t1.column1 * t1.column2) over (partition by t1.id) as SUM 
from t1 Inner Join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Tnx for help, now I try add where clausule after group by but get error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Where'.

Comment: @user_odoo u need to set the where clause before the group by...

I added a example

Answer (score 1):

Your intent is not clear. Probably this is what you meant (sum t1.column1 * t1.column2 grouping by id and t1.id exists in t2):

```
Select t1.id, sum(t1.column1 * t1.column2) as SUM 
from t1 where exists 
(select * from t2 where t1.id = t2.id)
group by t1.id;
```

Note: Do not sum joined tables. Sum and and join instead (here join has no purpose I think).

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
Select t1.id, SUM(t1.column1 * t1.column2) as SUM 
from t1 Inner Join t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
group by t1.id
```